# What's the proper PowerShell verb/pattern for get-or-create?

Tags: powershell, design-patterns, naming-conventions

I want to create a few PowerShell functions that create an item, or return existing item if it is already there. E.g. database login, folder, etc.

What is a proper verb for this? There is no `Ensure` in [Approved Verbs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714428(v=vs.85).aspx), and I am not sure what else would be applicable. I considered `New-X -IfExists ReturnExisting` but I would prefer to follow a common pattern instead of inventing my own.

Are there any built-in PowerShell commandlets that do get-or-create so that I can copy the approach?

Comment: I would probably use the `Get` verb and implicitly create a missing item, because getting the item is the primary objective. That's just my personal point of view, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the [approved verb listing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714428(v=vs.85).aspx):

**New vs. Set**
The New verb is used to create a new resource. The Set verb is used to modify an existing resource, optionally creating the resource if it does not exist, such as the Set-Variable cmdlet.

Comment: Hmm, Set might be what I need, though Set-Directory definitely sounds awkward, especially if I use the return value.

Comment: So add a -Passthrough switch to it and make it not output an object by default? That may make it feel more natural.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Get-Verb` to see the list of all approved verbs.  But for your case I would probably break up the function into two functions.  That is, if you care about following PowerShell idioms.  Use "New" to create a  and "Get" to get an existing .  OTOH, if this is just for you, use whatever you like.  :-)

Comment: The thing is, I want a function that does both -- it is needed often enough here to warrant a common function. As for using whatever I like -- that's a valid option but I wanted to know if there are already any existing examples by MS.

Answer (score 0):

Well with a folder i would assume `New` because you're creating a resource and you could program your function in such a way that if it already exists you return the object instead of creating it anew.

I have a function called `New-Box`, a function to create a new mailbox in our exchange environment, if the mailbox already exists i get my function to return the details rather then try creating a new one.

"The New verb is used to create a new resource. "

Comment: I just wonder if people using `New-` would expect it to fail if item already exists -- thus creating a potential for errors where existing item is returned instead of new one.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily get nit picky with this but I feel like *Resolve* might be something that could satisfy both needs to use or create in its absence. While it does not fit its only other cmdlet `Resolve-Path`, you could argue that you are trying *to deal with (a question, a matter of uncertainty, etc.) conclusively; settle; solve* the item. This is definitely a matter of personal option and much like Keith Hill said: to each his own.

[source](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/resolve)